# Performing calculations with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I have a question on how to perform a calculation with an array. In my case, I need to perform the calculation of an array and then call it in the main method. I did the calculation in the return type and the compiler complained that double cannot be converted to double[] so I tried getting the length of the array and still I got the same warning. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
// calcGravity returns an array of doubles containing teh gravity values
//and takes two arrays of doubles as parameters for the radius values and mass
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass)
{
    // fill in code here
        return (6.67E-17) * mass.length / Math.pow(radius.length, 2);
    // The formula to calculate gravity is:
    // 6.67E-17 times the massOfPlanet divided by the radius of the planet squared
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass){
   double[] grav = new double[radius.length]();
   for (int i =0; i<radius.length;i++) {
      grav[i] = (6.67E-17) * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2);
   }
   return grav;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass)
{
    double[] ret = new double[radius.length];
    for (int i=0;i<radius.length;i++) {
      // fill in code here
      ret[i] = (6.67E-17) * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2);
      // The formula to calculate gravity is:
      // 6.67E-17 times the massOfPlanet divided by the radius of the planet squared
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the calculation on each row individually.

```
double[] gravities = new double[radius.length]();

for (int i =0; i<radius.length;i++) {
  gravities[i] = (6.67E-17) * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2);
}
return gravities;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `double[]` is an array of doubles. You're just calculating one number. When you try to return a `double` and the return type is a `double[]`, the compiler can't convert that.

Your calculation is wrong. The lengths of `radius` and `mass` aren't the radius and mass. They each contain a bunch of numbers, each of which is a radius and a mass. You want to calculate each of the gravities for each mass/radius pair and return a new array containing those:

```
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass)
{
    // Check that you have the same number of radii as masses
    if (radius.length != mass.length)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot calculate gravities with unequal radii and masses.");

    double[] gravity = new double[radius.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < radius.length; i++) {
      double[i] = (6.67E-17) * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2);
    }
    return gravity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing `mass.length` and `radius.length`, you will get the number of elements in these arrays.

So you have to write a loop to iterate over all values in these arrays.

```
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass) {
    int size = radius.length;

    if (size != mass.length) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("can't calculate with different count of array elements!");
    }

    double[] sums = new double[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       sums[i] = (6.67E-17) * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2);
    }

    return sums;
}
```